# how to check if a pkg file is code signed

Tags: c++, code-signing

i am trying to check code signing status for a pkg file

what i have done is below steps:

(1) generate CFURLRef path for package
    CFURLRef path = ConvertCFURLFromPath(package);

(2) generate SecStaticCode from above path
OSStatus status = SecStaticCodeCreateWithPath(path, kSecCSDefaultFlags, &staticCode);

(3) Check StaticCode is signed or not
 status = SecStaticCodeCheckValidity(staticCode, kSecCSDoNotValidateExecutable, NULL);

However, i always got status "-67062" in above validation, while the path and static code look correct to me.

On that other hand, if i use the pktutil to check the package file, i can see the signed signature showing correctly.

So i am wondering if above API SecStaticCodeCheckValidity can be used to verify pkg file ? or it only work for app ?

what is missing in my steps ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the simplest - .pkg files (internally .xar archives) are NOT executables. They are neither Mach-o files, Code-bundles, or anything loadable for execution. They are mere "documents" opened by the Installer application. Hence, this API doesn't fit.

I think I read somewhere in the SecStaticCodeCreate() documentation that you COULD create such object for non-executable files, but I don't think you could validate them this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the certificate of a .pkg file using apple built in xar library, and then when you have your *SecCertificateRef* object, you can call the method *SecStaticCodeCheckValidity*

See example that should do the trick:

```
- (void)verifySigForXar:(NSString *)path
{
    OSStatus err = noErr;
    xar_t pkg = NULL;
    xar_signature_t sig = NULL;
    int32_t ncerts = 0;
    const uint8_t *data = NULL;
    uint32_t len = 0;
    SecCertificateRef tmp = NULL;
    int cur = 0;
    CFErrorRef cfError = NULL;

    pkg = xar_open([path UTF8String], READ);

    if (pkg == NULL) 
    {
        os_log_error("error opening Xar in path :%{public}s ", [path UTF8String]);
        return;
    }

    sig = xar_signature_first(pkg);

    if (sig == NULL) {
        os_log_error(g_logger, "error getting xar signature in path :%{public}s ", [path UTF8String]);
         return;
    }

    ncerts = xar_signature_get_x509certificate_count(sig);
    NSMutableArray *certs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //populate array of certs
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < ncerts; i++) 
    {
        if (xar_signature_get_x509certificate_data(sig, i, &data, &len) == -1) 
        {
            os_log_error("Unable to extract certificate data. xar signature in path :%{public}s ", [path UTF8String]);
            return;
        }

        const CSSM_DATA crt = { (CSSM_SIZE) len, (uint8_t *) data };
        err = SecCertificateCreateFromData(&crt, CSSM_CERT_X_509v3, CSSM_CERT_ENCODING_DER, &tmp);
        [certs addObject:(id)CFBridgingRelease(tmp)];
    }

    //iterate the array of 
    for (id certObj in certs) 
    {
        if (CFGetTypeID((__bridge CFTypeRef)object) == SecCertificateGetTypeID()) 
        {
              SecCertificateRef cert = (__bridge SecCertificateRef)certObj;
              err = SecStaticCodeCheckValidityWithErrors(codeRef, kSecCSDoNotValidateExecutable, NULL, &cfError);
              //
        }
  }

}
```